# How to select records from one table that does exists in another

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. `tl` and `t2`. Each table has the columns: `ID`, `name`. The `ID` is a PK and Auto increment. The two tables are not connected to each other. The `t2.name` is a subset of `t1.name`, but after adding `www.` at the beginning of the string  in the `name`. 
Ex:

```
`t1`.`name`= ggg
`t2`.`name`= www.ggg
```

What I am trying to do is: selecting all the record of where `t1.name` not inserted in `t2`. So I wrote the following query:

```
select concat('www.',name) 
from db.t1
LEFT JOIN db.t2 
ON t2.name = t1.name
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select name from db.t2);
```

But, I get 0 result. I am certain that there are records that are available in t1 but not in t2. How can I select all the names in t1 that are not in t2??

Comment: `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM db.t2)` will cause the query to return zero or all results depending on if the table t2 contains any or no rows since there is no condition on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select concat('www.',name) 
from db.t1
LEFT JOIN db.t2 ON t2.name = concat('www.', t1.name)
WHERE db.t2.name IS NULL
```

Comment: This returned all the records in t1.

Comment: Edited my answer. Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT('www.', tbl1.name)
FROM db.t1 AS tbl1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM db.t2 AT tbl2
    WHERE CONCAT('www.', tbl1.`name`) = tbl2.`name`
)
```

Comment: 1) I can not figure out what do you mean by `select 1` in your second select. 2) When I assume that is t2.name It did not work. It return all the records in t1.

Comment: In an exists tests all that matters is that there is, or is not, a result set.  By returning the value 1 instead of a record you decrease the amount of work to be done.

Comment: Not sure why this would return all of the records in t1.  It is explicitly stating to only return those records from t1 where there isn't a record in t2 that the name in t1, after adding www. to the beginning of it, matches a name in t2.  In the majority of cases, an EXISTS test is more performant than doing a JOIN and testing for NULL.  Only testing will confirm either way though.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
select t.name FROM
(
 select concat('www.',t1.name) AS name
 from t1
) t
LEFT JOIN t2
ON t2.name = t.name
WHERE t2.name IS NULL
```